# How to post to a page using FB.ui()?

Tags: facebook, sharing, fb.ui

I am trying to replicate the "share" functionality provided by the "share" link under a wall post: The dialog shows a dropdown box at the top allowing me to choose whether to post to my timeline, in a group, the wall of a page I manage (etc).

Ideally I'd like to able to do this without having to get extended permissions from the user. So I tried FB.ui() but could only get "Post to your wall" to post to the user's timeline. It doesn't have the same dropdown box at the top.

Accordiong to [the doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) I should be able to provide a page id as the "from" parameter to enable users to use the dialog to post to a page (assuming they are admins of the page). So I tried this but I always get the same "Post to your wall" dialog (even tho I'm admin of the page given).

The doc page contains a link [How can I use the Feed Dialog to post on a Facebook Fan Page wall not liked by the user?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9196168/timeline) but it's a dead link :-[

So can it be done using the dialog? Or do I have to get "manage_pages" permission and post to /pageId/feed ([as here](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/691425/how-do-you-post-to-the-wall-on-a-facebook-page-not-profile/3429737#3429737))?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the old sharer.php can do what I want, but Facebook says it's deprecated and the doc page [http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share) redirects back to [http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) - which is where I started.

Comment: Check this link for the old `sharer.php` http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/share-links/

Comment: Thanks @AnveshSaxena. So am I wrong to believe sharer.php is deprecated? I see it's listed in the [social plugins page[(http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/).

Comment: I don't think so, but I see a lot of people saying that it is, but if it would have been, then the same would have been listed in the documentation page. So I can safely say it is not depreciated. Also, if this is the answer, please do add and accept it so people in future may get solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems today I *can* do it using the feed dialog after all. I tried apage based on the example in [the doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) added my page id as the "from" parameter and it works.

I need to be logged on as a page admin, but I don't need to be "using Facebook as" the page.